# Display custom field Woocommerce category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

Im trying to Display a custom field in Woocommerce category archive page
In my functions php I create my Term prix_min_cat and Save it. and its working in same pages but without a loop.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'custom_add_catg_min_price', 12);
 function custom_add_catg_min_price ($category) {
 $cat_id        =    $category->term_id;
 $prod_term    =    get_term($cat_id,'product_cat');
 $minprice=    $prod_term->prix_min_cat;
  echo '<p class="showcase-item-addendum">'.$minprice.'</p>';
}
```

How I can display my Term value

Comment: As per your question the static text is displayed in the correct place, so you just use the parameter of $category in function. And inside the function just use print_r($category); and share the output.

Comment: Its not working I tryed print_r  minprice

Comment: print_r($category)

Comment: It shows all WP Terms objects

Comment: did you find term?

Comment: No I didnt find them. only name & description. but with this code I can display Description & banner of cateory and others Custom fields

Comment: Its not an issue with above code you have to check category

Answer (score 0):

You could tweak this code to display term value:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'wpm_product_cat_display_details_meta' );
/**
 * Display details meta on Product Category archives.
 *
 */
function wpm_product_cat_display_details_meta() {

    if ( ! is_tax( 'product_cat' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $t_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
    $details = get_term_meta( $t_id, 'details', true ); //'details' is your term value

    if ( '' !== $details ) { //'details' is your term value
        ?>
        <div class="product-cat-details">
            <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', wp_kses_post( $details ) ); ?> //'details' is your term value
        </div>
        <?php
    }

}
```

You should be able to adapt this to make it work. Otherwise, here is the Source: http://www.wpmusketeer.com/add-a-wysiwyg-field-to-woocommerce-product-category-page/